# Photoshop Generate Image Assets outputs wrong size image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a 1440x280 resolution image. It looks like this:

[image]

The layers are grouped and I rename the group like this:

[image]

```
1024 x 200 test-image70%
```

This should output a 1024x200 px JPG at 70% quality. Instead it spits out this 1028x532 jpg:

[image]

Huh? What in the world is going on here? This isn't remotely close to what I am expecting. What am I doing wrong here? Is using groups really buggy with Generate Image Assets?

This is Photoshop CC 2015.5.1

(Note: Ignore all the black borders in the screenshots, that is just the Photoshop canvas background color).

Comment: I tried this with identical elements, as far as I could tell, and exactly the same filename. It definitely did output the image at 1024x200px size. No matter what the original document or image size was, it stretched the **** out of it in order to save it at the right size. Could even be a bug that could be fixed by trashing the preferences or updating photoshop or something. Never bumped into this before, so I'm personally kind of out of ideas. If yo could post like a dropbox link to the file, I could check out and see if it's your Photoshop or.. something with the file.

Comment: I tested your settings in Photoshop CC 2017(.0.1) and I got the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Set your document size at 1024x200 px.
Then you should apply layer mask or vector mask at your layer group, also in 1024x200 pixel.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a mask (either a vector mask or a bitmap mask) to your `1024 x 200 text-image.jpg70%` group, the mask will dictate the bounding box when exporting the image using Generator.

Please note that using a layer or group mask works for PNG and JPEG exports, but it seems like there’s a bug when exporting SVGs using Generator with masks — the mask bounds are not used. I realise that doesn’t apply in this specific case, but it’s worth noting for other readers.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the same problem with Image > Trim (Photoshop CC 2017)

Comment: trimming doesn't solve the question being asked